# Remove white space from table cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-tables

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    ...
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
        <button class="btn btn-info mini"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-default mini">09:00</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default mini">09:30</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default mini">10:00</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default mini">10:30</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default mini">11:00</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block chev down"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
    </div>
  </td>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BravoZulu/k2e7gLrh/3/)

And I want to remove the extra space next to my button-group so that there's little margin on either side. Each button has a fixed width and so does the button group:

CSS:

```
.btn-group {
  width: 117px;
}

.btn-group-sm > .btn.mini {
  padding: 5px 3px;
  width: 40px;
}

.btn-group > .btn.mini:first-child:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
  border-radius: 0;
}

 .btn-group > .btn.mini:first-child {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.btn-group-sm>.btn.mini,
.btn.chev {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn.chev {
  width: 118px;
}
```

I've already tried using `margin: 0` and trying to fix the column width, but with no luck so far.

Comment: Tried to set the border of the cells to zero?

Comment: Hmm. JSFiddle is down at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your table there is a `padding:5px;` you have to overwrite it with the following:

```
table.table {
    width: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}

/** only for the head of the table. */
table.table thead th {
    padding:0;
}

/** only for the body of the table. */
table.table tbody td {
    padding:0;
}
```

Make sure you place this CSS after the CSS of Bootstrap! Additonaly remove all classes on the `th` (named `col-md-1`). The space should be removed like this example: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/3obsbh5n/2/

Comment: This removes the padding from the left, but not from the right:
[jsfiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/BravoZulu/k2e7gLrh/4/)
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a padding of 5px tied to `table-condensed tbody>tr>td` in the Bootstrap CSS. You can override this with your own style is several ways. A simple example would be to add a class to some `td` elements where you are going to have buttons:

`<td class="buttonCell">`

And override the Bootstrap style by using something like this:

`.table-condensed tbody>tr>td.buttonCell {
  padding: 0px;
}`